# Swing change foreground color of BasicArrowButton

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, jspinner, uimanager

In `JSpinner` class, how would I change the foreground color of two `BasicArrowButton`(up and down) components?
the `component.setForeground(<<a_color>>)` doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.
**EDIT**

```
private void set_colors(JSpinner spinner){
    int n = spinner.getComponentCount();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        Component c = spinner.getComponent(i);
        System.out.println(c);
        if (c instanceof BasicArrowButton)
        {
            c.setForeground(ds_conn_text.getForeground());//doesn't work, doesn't change arrow color
            c.setBackground(ds_conn_text.getBackground());
            BasicArrowButton c0=(BasicArrowButton) c;c0.setBorder(ok_button.getBorder());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a follow-up question of [Swing change the JSpinner back and fore colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127833/swing-change-the-jspinner-back-and-fore-colors)

It is not possible to *only* set the color of the arrows without overriding the `paint` method. The reason is simply that the color for the arrows is the same color as the color that is used for the "shadows" of the buttons. So you *could* put the line

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("controlDkShadow", Color.MAGENTA);
```

somewhere into your `main`, but this would not only change the arrow colors, but also other elements' colors which actually should *not* be changed.

An ugly/hacky way to set this color *only* for a particular instance would be

```
private static void hackilySetColor(JSpinner spinner, Color color)
{
    int n = spinner.getComponentCount();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        Component c = spinner.getComponent(i);
        if (c instanceof BasicArrowButton)
        {
            try
            {
                Field field = BasicArrowButton.class.getDeclaredField("darkShadow");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(c, color);
                field.setAccessible(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this uses reflection, is really an **ugly hack**, and still replaces the color of the "dark shadow" border of the buttons.

You'll be better off with an own UI for things like this (or ... just don't change the color at all - this seems rather useless for me anyhow...)

Comment: just don't change the color at all == use proper L&F